# MySQL include 0 count items in a group by query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query similar to this:

```
SELECT Zip, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM people 
WHERE specialty='Driver' 
GROUP BY Zip 
ORDER BY Zip
```

It's filtering out results with a 0 count, but I still want all of the grouped zips even if the count is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT Zip, SUM(specialty = 'Driver') as count 
FROM people 
GROUP BY Zip 
ORDER BY Zip
```

Comment: What about more complicated WHERE statements ex `WHERE specialty='Driver' AND state='CA'`

Comment: Just put all that in the aggregation `SUM(specialty='Driver' AND state='CA')`